# How to retrieve the storyline paragraph with imdbpy?

Tags: python, imdb, imdbpy

So far, I haven't figured out how to retrieve the short description paragraph from imdb with imdbpy.

I can retrieve a very (very) long plot this way though :

```
ia = IMDb()
movie = ia.search_movie("brazil")
movie = movie[0]
movie = ia.get_movie(movie.movieID)

plot = movie.get('plot', [''])[0]
plot = plot.split('::')[0]
```

The last line removes the submitter username.

In the HTML source, the block I'm looking for is markedup as `<p itemprop="description">`.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
description = movie.get('plot outline')
```

This code will get a list of the type of information available for a movie:

```
movie.keys()
```